# Comma separated value not being stored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, arrays

I have a model called org and department. Whenever a organization sign up, it must create a list of departments it has by entering the name of departments as comma separated value. The department list can also be edited later. These are my models:

*0rg*

```
class Org < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :name, :website, :department_list
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :website, presence: true

  def department_list
    departments.collect { |d| d.department_name }.join(', ')
  end

  def department_list=(text)
    if id && text
      departments.destroy_all
      text.split(',').each do |d|
        departments.create(department_name: d.strip.capitalize)
      end
   end
 end
end
```

*Department*

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :department_name, :org_id
  belongs_to :org
end
```

*My view*

```
<%= f.text_area :department_list, :cols => "10", :rows => "10" %>
```

**Problem:**

When the organization sign up by entering the department name as comma separated value, it is not stored in the  database. But when the organization updates the field later by edit action, only then department name is stored and it can be further edited at any time. I want the department name to be stored when organization sign up.

Please Help.

**EDIT:**

My Registration Controller:

```
class Webs::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /resource/sign_up

  def new
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    # customized code begin

    # create a new child instance depending on the given user type



    child_class = params[:web][:user_type].camelize.constantize
    resource.role = child_class.new(params[child_class.to_s.underscore.to_sym])

    # first check if child instance is valid
    # cause if so and the parent instance is valid as well
    # it's all being saved at once
    valid = resource.valid?
    valid = resource.role.valid? && valid

    # customized code end

    if valid && resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
     clean_up_passwords resource
     render :new
    end
 end

 # GET /resource/edit
 def edit
   render :edit
 end

 # PUT /resource
 # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
 # the current user in place.
 def update

   self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
   prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

   if resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
      resource.role.update_attributes(params[:org])
      resource.role.update_attributes(params[:user])
      if is_navigational_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
   else
      clean_up_passwords resource
     render :edit
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: perhaps there is a problem in your condition **if id && text**. First check it using debugger where its coming to it or not

Comment: @krishnasahoo: That's pretty close to an answer. `id.nil?` will be true when creating a new record so calling `department_list=` will do nothing.

Comment: So you should first create a record of **Org**. Then try to save the department_list. Otherwise **after_create** to save the records of department_list

Comment: Please elaborate. Where should i use after_create and what should that function do?

Comment: either you use `after_save` callback function or simply after saving your org model data assign `org.department_list = text`

Comment: Which function should i call in after_save ? Do i need to modify my present code.

Comment: Please show your controller